# Get expanded item in collapsible list

Tags: jquery-mobile

If I have a collapsible list in JQM, how to I get the item that is expanded?

I've tried; `$("#addressMDUList").find(":selected").text()` but that doesn't work.

So I have;

```
<div id="addressMDUList" data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d">
```

and the sets are added programmatically.  Now, just before I rebuild the list, I want to get the set the user last had open, rebuild the list, and then open that set again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Collapsed *collapsible* has class `ui-collapsible-collapsed`, this class is removed once a *collapsible* is expanded. Inside a *collapsible-set* there should be only one expanded *collapsible* or none.

All you need to filter the expanded one using `.not(".ui-collapsible-collapsed")`.

```
var expanded = $("col-set-id").find(".ui-collapsible").not(".ui-collapsible-collapsed");
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/uW9X9/)**